# Case agreement of preposition "von" when there are two objects

Tags: preposition, objects

> Die Älteren erzählten gerne von ihrer Kinder und Jugend.

The above sentence came from [this](http://lang-8.com/593877/journals/198503020805908837974912316517118681436) language learning site.

We know that *von* is a preposition that should be used with the *dative* case.

The dative article/pronoun for plural *Kinder* should be *den* or *ihren*; while that for singluar feminine *Jugend* is *der*.

So - correct me if I am wrong - the grammatically sound sentence should be rendered as:

> Die Älteren erzählten gerne von ihren Kinder und ihrer Jugend.

Meaning, old people love talk about their children and their youth.

Since this is a suggested answer for a *Lückenstest* that's been circulating around the web, my preferred interpretation would rather be:

> Die Älteren erzählten gerne von ihrer Kindheit und Jugendzeit.

Both *Kindheit* and *Jugendzeit* are feminine singular, so *ihrer* would agree with both objects.

---

## The Question:

Is it a necessity to repeat the article or pronoun when verbs with prepositions that dictate case contain multiple objects with different gender and/or number?

Comment: It looks like a mistake in the text. It should be *Die Älteren erzählten gerne von ihrer Kindheit und Jugend*. This sounds most idiomatic and fits context. There is no need to add -zeit to Jugend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Correct me if I'm wrong

Ok :D

> Die Älteren erzählten gerne von ihren Kinder und ihrer Jugend.

Kinder needs the plural dative case:

> Die Älteren erzählten gerne von ihren **Kindern** und ihrer Jugend.

Regarding your question:

Yes, you need an extra article or pronoun, if they would be different. You also need two articles or pronouns if they would be the same but you want to clarify, that they are two different things/people you are talking about.

> Gestern erzählte ich von...
>   ... meiner Freundin und meinem Hund.
>   ... meiner Arbeit und meinen Kollegen.
>   ... meiner Arbeit und Kollegen *(indefinite plural here)*
>   ... Kollegen und meiner Arbeit *(just the previous example reversed)*
>   ... dem Mann und der Frau
>   ... dem Mann und seinem Bruder
>   ... dem Arzt und dem Piloten *(two different people)*
>   ... dem Arzt und Piloten *(the same person is a doctor and pilot)*
>   ... meinem Morgen, Nachmittag und Abend *(words form a unit)*